# How to modify string values and convert them to int, bool etc?

Tags: python

Below is the function I'm trying to define however unsuccessful. I can simplest python built-ins to complete this.

```
def clean_data(data: List[List[str]]) -> None:
    """Modify data so that the applicable string values are converted to their
    appropriate type.

    The indexes of the string values that are converted, and their
    corresponding type, are:
        - COLUMN_RIDING is an int
        - COLUMN_VOTER is an int
        - COLUMN_RANK is a list of strings
        - COLUMN_RANGE is a list of integers
        - COLUMN_APPROVAL is a list of booleans

    >>> row = ['0', '1', 'NDP;Liberal;Green;CPC', '1;4;2;3', 'NO;YES;NO;NO']
    >>> clean_data([row])
    >>> row == SAMPLE_DATA_1[0]
    True
    >>> row = ['117', '12', 'Liberal;CPC;NDP;Green', '4;0;5;0', 'YES;NO;YES;NO']
    >>> clean_data([row])
    >>> row == [117, 12, ['CPC', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL', 'NDP'], [4, 0, 5, 0], [True, False, True, False]
    True
    """
    
    clean = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if COLUMN_RIDING[i] == str:
            clean.append(
    return clean
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your example:

```
>>> row = ['117', '12', 'Liberal;CPC;NDP;Green', '4;0;5;0', 'YES;NO;YES;NO']
>>> clean_data([row])
>>> row == [117, 12, ['CPC', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL', 'NDP'], [4, 0, 5, 0], [True, False, True, False]
```

You have the right idea of looping through the data.

It appears that *COLUMN_RANK*, *COLUMN_RANGE* and *COLUMN_APPROVAL* are lists separated by a ";". Therefore, if we find a ";" in the string, we should split the string and iterate through it. When we iterate, we should detect if it's either an integer, *YES/NO* for boolean, or otherwise its a string.

If it's *COLUMN_RIDING* or *COLUMN_VOTER*, just append as an integer

```
def clean_data(data):
    clean = []
    for column in data:
        if ";" in column:
            tmp = []
            for value in column.split(";"):
                if value.isdigit(): #'4;0;5;0'
                    tmp.append(int(value))
                elif value == "YES":
                    tmp.append(bool(value))
                elif value == "NO":
                    tmp.append(False)
                else: #['CPC', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL', 'NDP']
                    tmp.append(value.upper())
            clean.append(tmp)
        else:
            clean.append(int(column))
    return clean
```